# Error in shape (dimention) and type of Keras model input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, layer

I am desperate to set the Input shape of this simple Keras model :(
Both X and Y are numpy.narray but I don't know what's the wrong with it! I tried different X shape but the error is there! The info of the datasets (dimentions, number of samples, etc.) is available in the code.
The .pkl file for X_train is got from hidden state of a pre-trained model.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import Input, Model
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

############################## X_Train ############################

X_Train_3embed1 = pd.read_pickle("XX_Train_3embeding.pkl")


X_Train_3embed = np.array(X_Train_3embed1)

print("X-Train")
print(X_Train_3embed.shape)   # (230, 1, 128)
print(type(X_Train_3embed))  # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(X_Train_3embed[0].shape) # (1, 128)
print(type(X_Train_3embed[0])) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>


############################## Y_Train ############################

Y_Train_labels_list = pd.read_pickle("lis_Y_all_Train.pkl")

print(type(Y_Train_labels_list))  #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(Y_Train_labels_list[0])) #<class 'str'>

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y_Train_labels_list)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y_Train_labels_list)
Y_my_Train = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)


print("Y-Train")
print(Y_my_Train.shape) #(230, 83)
print(type(Y_my_Train)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(Y_my_Train[0].shape) # (83,)
print(type(Y_my_Train[0])) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

##################################  Model  ##################################

first_input = Input(shape=(1, 128))

first_dense = Dense(128)(first_input)

output_layer = Dense(83, activation='softmax')(first_dense)

model = Model(inputs=first_input, outputs=output_layer)

model.summary()


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])


history = model.fit((X_Train_3embed, Y_my_Train), epochs=2, batch_size=32)
```

Here is the result:

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 1, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1, 128)            16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1, 83)             10707     
=================================================================
Total params: 27,219
Trainable params: 27,219
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vahideh/PycharmProjects/3KArgen-master/MyTransferClassifier2.py", line 63, in <module>
    history = model.fit((X_Train_3embed, Y_my_Train), epochs=2, batch_size=32)
  File "/home/vahideh/PycharmProjects/MyVirtualEnvs/MyKargo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1154, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/vahideh/PycharmProjects/MyVirtualEnvs/MyKargo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/home/vahideh/PycharmProjects/MyVirtualEnvs/MyKargo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 99, in standardize_input_data
    data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
  File "/home/vahideh/PycharmProjects/MyVirtualEnvs/MyKargo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 99, in <listcomp>
    data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
  File "/home/vahideh/PycharmProjects/MyVirtualEnvs/MyKargo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 34, in standardize_single_array
    elif x.ndim == 1:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

How can I feed these dataset to the model? or change the input shape of the model?

Comment: remove the tuple... model.fit(X_Train_3embed, Y_my_Train, epochs=2, batch_size=32)

Comment: another thing shouldn't be your `X_Train_3embed[0].shape` of shape `(128,)` in the comment ?

Comment: so how train the model?

Comment: try how Macro said it

Comment: @MarcoCerliani what do you suggest to use instead of model.fit(X_Train_3embed, Y_my_Train, epochs=2, batch_size=32)  for training the model?

Comment: What is the problem in using what I suggested to u?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I don't know which tuple you mean to remove it?! I see no tuple

Comment: 'remove the tuple' i.e. not wrap your dataset inside tuple i.e. not use tuple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your models output is of shape `(None, 1, 83)` i.e each samples ouptput is `1 x 83` but your ground truth for each sample is a scalar. There are two way to deal with this problem

1. Flatten the outputs and continue using your data
2. Remove the unnecessary dimension in your data i.e flatten each sample from `1X128` to just `128` and change the model architecture to deal with 1D data which will result in output being 1D.

Fixed code:

#### Approach 1

```
from keras import Input, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
import numpy as np

# Dummy data
X_Train_3embed = np.random.randn(230, 1, 128)
Y_my_Train = np.random.randn(230, 83)

#model
first_input = Input(shape=(1, 128))
first_dense = Dense(128)(first_input)
output_layer = Dense(83, activation='softmax')(first_dense)
outputs = Flatten()(output_layer)

model = Model(inputs=first_input, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
model.fit(X_Train_3embed, Y_my_Train, epochs=2, batch_size=32)
```

Output:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_10 (InputLayer)        [(None, 1, 128)]          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 1, 128)            16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 1, 83)             10707     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_6 (Flatten)          (None, 83)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 27,219
Trainable params: 27,219
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/2
8/8 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 6.2275 - acc: 0.0162
Epoch 2/2
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2639 - acc: 0.0150
```

#### Approach 2

```
# Dummy data
X_Train_3embed = np.random.randn(230, 1, 128)
Y_my_Train = np.random.randn(230, 83)

#model
first_input = Input(shape=(128))
first_dense = Dense(128)(first_input)
outputs = Dense(83, activation='softmax')(first_dense)

model = Model(inputs=first_input, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
model.fit(X_Train_3embed.reshape(-1,128), Y_my_Train, epochs=2, batch_size=32)
```

Output:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_13 (InputLayer)        [(None, 128)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)             (None, 128)               16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_25 (Dense)             (None, 83)                10707     
=================================================================
Total params: 27,219
Trainable params: 27,219
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/2
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: -1.1705 - acc: 0.0100
Epoch 2/2
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: -6.3587 - acc: 0.0015
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem still remains and I noticed that my Input shape in model summary is different from yours, mine is: input_1 (InputLayer) (None, 1, 128) 0 but you have an extra [] in the input: input_10 (InputLayer) [(None, 1, 128)] 0, I should convert it to list?

Comment: I converted X_Train_3embed to list by list(X_Train_3embed), but it didn't work:|
The .pkl file is the hidden state of a layer of another pretrained model... they mightnot be tensors?! I totally confused :(

Comment: Can you tell me what is the output of `X_Train_3embed.shape`. Also in approach 1 I am using your model architecture expect that I added a flatten layer at the end. In keras you don't feed in tensors you feed in numpy arrays and framework takes care of converting it into tensors. Pytorch on the other hand needs tensors.

Comment: I noticed that the problem arose coz I used an extra bracket in fit function! Tnx alot :), so if I add an extra dimension to the input: (1,128) -> (1,62, 128), it doesn't work, in this case I should put the Flatten layer after first_dense and before output_layer, right?!

Comment: You can have the model consume any dimension you want but at the last layer since the label is scalar (per sample) you need a mechanism to compress all those dimensions to single and flatten is one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically MarcoCerliani is asking you to remove the tuple

Your code: `model.fit((X_Train_3embed, Y_my_Train), epochs=2, batch_size=32)`

Changed code: `model.fit(X_Train_3embed, Y_my_Train, epochs=2, batch_size=32)`